# Saving value in ASP.NET Session variable

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, session-variables, intptr

How can I save `IntPtr` value in `Session` variable?
I could do this but How can I parse it back to `IntPtr`.

```
 IntPtr _intPtrVariable = IntPtr.Zero; 
 Session["ADUserToken"] = _intPtrVariable;
```

Comment: `IntPtr whatever = (IntPtr)Session["ADUserToken"];`

Comment: In general it is **wrong** to keep a `IntPtr` in the `Session`, because the `Session` could be shared by multiple machines or the server could be rebooted between calls to the server, invalidating the `IntPtr`.

Answer (score 2):

You can value back from session like below:

```
if( Session["ADUserToken"] != null)
{
    IntPtr? sessionValue = Session["ADUserToken"] as IntPtr?;
}
```

Comment: It shows me this error 

"The as operator must be used with a reference type or nullable type ('System.IntPtr' is a non-nullable value type) "

Comment: You need to add ? for nullable types. Please check my updated answer.

Comment: Yes it converts successfully. but the variable cannot be used in WindowsIdentity.Impersonate (_intPtrVariable); method. It shows this error; "cannot convert from 'System.IntPtr?' to 'ref System.Threading.StackCrawlMark'"

Comment: @YesudassMoses I think you need to pass like this.  WindowsIdentity.Impersonate(System.IntPtr.Zero);

Comment: No, I am just telling the argument is IntPtr instance. Its not the code.

Comment: [Please check this link about WindowsIdentity.Impersonate() method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/chf6fbt4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: Anyway, I get it working using (IntPtr)Session["ADUserToken"];
as suggested by Sriram Sakthivel. Thanks so much friends :)

Comment: @YesudassMoses You need: `if (sessionValue != null) { DoSomething(sessionValue.Value); }`

Comment: This is the current code, and it's working fine now.       
           if (Session["ADUserToken"] != null)
            {

                IntPtr userToken = (IntPtr)Session["ADUserToken"];
                clsImpersonation.ImpersonateMe(userToken);
            }